# How do I prevent git from thinking new directories are part of the working tree?

Tags: git, git-bash

My home directory is a git repository. But to allow me to freely create/delete/test code without cluttering up `git status`, my .gitignore has an explicit ignore all:

```
[svenglar@my_box ~]$ cat ~/.gitignore
## Ignore everything by default.
## Use 'git add --force <file>' to add a file/dir.
*
```

I assume that that means when I create a new directory, it will not be included in the repository. But that doesn't seem to be the case:

```
[svenglar@my_box ~]$ git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
true
[svenglar@my_box ~]$ mkdir test
[svenglar@my_box ~]$ cd test
[svenglar@my_box ~/test]$ git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
true
[svenglar@my_box ~/test]$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I see that `git status` is clean, but `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree` thinks the new directory is part of the repository.

**So my question is, how can I configure git to not consider new directories to be part of the working tree?**

--**UPDATE**--

**The reason** I'm asking this in the first place is because I use .git-prompt.sh to modify BASH's prompt when I'm working with my git repos. I have multiple projects (folders) under my home folder that are git repos. 
When I cd to one of those directories, I like to see which branch is active, etc...

But I don't need/want to use .git-prompt.sh when I'm in the "home" repository because I don't consider that a "work" directory.

**My fix** is to modify .git-prompt.sh with the following check before the last "printf" command:

```
 # Only modify $PS1 if we are not in the home repository.
 [[ $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) =~ "${HOME}/" ]] && printf -- "$printf_format" "$c${b##refs/heads/}${f:+ $f}$r$p"
```

I was previously only checking if `pwd` contained `${HOME}/` (the last forward slash meaning I was in a subdirectory).

Thanks for all your answers. They helped me understand why I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

Use `strace git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree` to see what it is doing. If deep inside the tree you see many of these:

```
chdir("..")                             = 0
stat(".git", 0x7fff22ababa0)            = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Git just looks for a `.git` dir all the way up the file system. If it finds one, you are inside a working tree.

Instead of excluding things from your git, you can just set up your working tree in a dedicated subdirectory and use symlinks to explicitly add things you want to track.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me fix my underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

Git thinks everything is inside the working tree.  `.gitignore` simply tells git what files to ignore when committing.  Your better off not using your home directory as your repo root.  Instead, use a sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. And that makes sense.

Any directory under `.git` is considered to be part of the project. Otherwise, how would you work with source code at all?

If you really don't want that, have the git repository as a bare outside your `$HOME`, set the `GIT_DIR` in your environment; then set `GIT_WORK_TREE` to your `$HOME` when you want to work with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and yes, that does make sense now.